# Turn-off gdb "Inferior exited normally" messages

Tags: gdb

Is there a way to turn off

> [Inferior 1 (process 18410) exited normally]
>
> Warning: not running or target is remote

messages from gdb?

I've tried:

1. set logging off
2. set verbose off
3. set print thread-events off
4. set print inferior-events off

with no success

Comment: From a look at GDB's source code, this printing seems unconditional, so you can't avoid it.